# Getting Max URL length exceeded c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
  function GetUserEditProfileDetails() {
    var res = {};

    res.ID = parseInt($("#User_ID_EditProfile").val());
    res.FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
    res.LastName = $("#LastName").val();

    res.EmailId = $("#EmailId").val();
    res.Mobile = $("#Mobile").val();
    res.ProfilePic = $(".ProfilePic").attr("src");

    return res;
}

 $.ajax({
        url: "Profile/UpdateUser",             
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: GetUserEditProfileDetails(),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
        }
    })
```

By using above code, I am trying to save the details of a user. But when the profile pic is too long then the controller method is not calling and it shows internal server error.

Comment: adjust `maxAllowedContentLength` to increase the limit

Comment: Check your web.config and adjust `maxAllowedContentLength` in `requestLimits` element to larger number (maximum is 4,294,967,295 or around 4 GB).

Comment: Its Working. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please check below solution :

You need to change **maxAllowedContentLength** in Web.Config File :

**In system.web :**

```html
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

**And in system.webServer**

```html
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

**Cheers !!**